# What is magic used in proxifier?

Tags: http, proxy, ssh, chain

today i used bitvise tunnelier for tunneling and i set the listening proxy in mozilla. but unlucky tunnelier didn't rcognize the proxy protocol. here the output.

```
19:45:17.893 Initializing SOCKS / HTTP CONNECT proxy on 127.0.0.1:1080 succeeded.
19:46:02.266 (unrecognized proxy protocol) connection from 127.0.0.1:60300 failed: Unsupported client protocol; the client may be expecting a regular HTTP proxy.
19:46:03.991 (unrecognized proxy protocol) connection from 127.0.0.1:60301 failed: Unsupported client protocol; the client may be expecting a regular HTTP proxy.
19:46:05.803 (unrecognized proxy protocol) connection from 127.0.0.1:60302 failed: Unsupported client protocol; the client may be expecting a regular HTTP proxy.
19:46:27.439 (unrecognized proxy protocol) connection from 127.0.0.1:60303 failed: Unsupported client protocol; the client may be expecting a regular HTTP proxy.
19:46:28.280 (unrecognized proxy protocol) connection from 127.0.0.1:60304 failed: Unsupported client protocol; the client may be expecting a regular HTTP proxy.
19:46:50.534 (unrecognized proxy protocol) connection from 127.0.0.1:60305 failed: Unsupported client protocol; the client may be expecting a regular HTTP proxy.
19:46:50.578 (unrecognized proxy protocol) connection from 127.0.0.1:60306 failed: Unsupported client protocol; the client may be expecting a regular HTTP proxy.
19:47:21.361 (unrecognized proxy protocol) connection from 127.0.0.1:60307 failed: Unsupported client protocol; the client may be expecting a regular HTTP proxy.
```

I didn't know whats wrong with this. So i decided to install Proxifier aaaand BINGO!! it worked!!. here the output after using proxifier:

```
19:51:26.433 Accepted HTTP CONNECT connection from 127.0.0.1:60598 to 173.194.38.140:80.
19:51:26.434 Accepted HTTP CONNECT connection from 127.0.0.1:60601 to 173.194.38.140:80.
19:51:26.434 Accepted HTTP CONNECT connection from 127.0.0.1:60604 to 173.194.38.139:80.
19:51:26.434 Accepted HTTP CONNECT connection from 127.0.0.1:60607 to 173.194.38.139:80.
19:51:26.435 Accepted HTTP CONNECT connection from 127.0.0.1:60610 to 173.194.38.139:80.
19:51:26.435 Accepted HTTP CONNECT connection from 127.0.0.1:60613 to 173.194.38.140:80.
19:51:26.435 Accepted HTTP CONNECT connection from 127.0.0.1:60616 to 173.194.38.140:80.
19:51:26.435 Accepted HTTP CONNECT connection from 127.0.0.1:60619 to 173.194.38.140:80.
19:51:26.435 Accepted HTTP CONNECT connection from 127.0.0.1:60622 to 173.194.38.140:80.
19:51:26.436 Accepted HTTP CONNECT connection from 127.0.0.1:60625 to 173.194.38.140:80.
19:51:26.436 Accepted HTTP CONNECT connection from 127.0.0.1:60628 to 173.194.38.140:80.
19:51:26.436 Accepted HTTP CONNECT connection from 127.0.0.1:60631 to 74.125.235.15:80.
19:51:26.436 Accepted HTTP CONNECT connection from 127.0.0.1:60634 to 74.125.235.15:80.
19:51:48.413 Closing HTTP CONNECT connection from 127.0.0.1:60328, sent: 1060, received: 3609.
```

And in the other case, few days ago i used privoxy with Mozilla. but unfortunately the ip i used blocking facebook page. So i decided to use proxifier again to chain with privoxy.. aaaand bingo again.. it worked!!!

So guys, do you know what is really happened in Proxifier?. for some reason i need to use this feature in my Ubuntu desktop :) . please tell me if you know something about this :)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Ok guys thanks for helping me, but i have found the answer bymyself :p.. okay, it's called proxy chaining, the proxyfier make 2 output from one input (imho). first output is dirctly to proxy that we set to proxifier and the second output is from dns that set in the proxifier. so those two make diffrent way of the output.

```
firefox >> proxifier >>> 1. to dns server >> internet
                         2. to proxyserver we set >> internet
```

here example of my case:
i use privoxy to add header host on http connection, but unfortunately it would make bad request because there are 2 hosts in one request.
firefox >> privoxy(with two hosts header) === bad request

so you need something to resolve the problem. yes right it is a proxychaining app with dns support.
firefox >> proxifier >> privoxy(with two hosts header) === good request :)

So you need something app with dns support for chaining with dns server to resolve the bad request..

if you found my opinion is wrong please correct me, because it is just my humble opinion :)